# Software or tool for investigating groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, math-software

I'm interested in software that has the ability to investigate finite groups. In particular, I'd like to be able to ask it questions like "What are the solutions to $x^3 = 1$?" (i.e. find cube roots of unity) for a permutation group.

I've had a look at Maxima but don't see a way to ask it do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical anwer is [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).

(You can use it from inside Sage)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you happen to know if GAP will solve roots of unity for finite groups?

Comment: You can say, for example, `Filtered(SymmetricGroup(6), x -> x*x*x = ());` to get the list of elements of order three. I'm sure there are smarter ways :-)

Comment: OOh, sold! Thanks so much!

Comment: In larger groups, you could start by finding conjugacy class representatives and then looking for elements of order $3$ among these. Or if the order of the group is divisible by a relatively small power of $3$, you could first find a Sylow $3$-subgroup and look for its conjugacy classes.

Comment: Hi @DerekHolt, thanks for that info. I'm interested also in the analytical side also obviously.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Magma](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system)), but unlike GAP it is not (in general) free.